# Using an old Bluetooth-enabled Blackberry as a GPS

Tags: fpga, bluetooth, gps, mobile

I have a few Blackberry devices with integrated GPS functionality.  Given that the SIM is no longer activated, is it possible to use this device as a second hand GPS unit?

My thought is that I can communicate with it over Bluetooth with my custom FPGA.

Has this been done before?

Comment: "my custom ASIC"? I think that may be a bit optimistic.

Comment: @BrianCarlton I can't believe I wrote that... I think I was multitasking as I posted the question.  tks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On my BB I can't use the GPS without any data plan. GPS use data for faster Time to first fix. Technically it can work standalone, but perhaps RIM/Carrier has blocked it.
I'd really recommend you pick up one of the many GPS modules available:

https://www.sparkfun.com/categories/4

Why add bluetooth and wireless headaches if you don't need to?

Answer (score 2):

Well, if the GSM on the device can be activated and accessed through the BT then you are OK to use it, but I am not sure you will be able to use the BT to control the GPS functionality of your mobile phone.

In order to test this, you may find it easier to use a PC with BT and try to get that working first, if you manage to do that, then implementing BT communication with FPGA is not a big deal, it is a bit over kill, but it is definitely possible.